# create list from DocumentSnapshot in flutter

Tags: list, flutter

Ok, I am fairly new to flutter/Dart and I have learned a lot. However, I need help in understanding how to add data from a Firestore DocumentSnapshot to a list.

I am trying to use the .addAll but I am sure I am using it wrong.

```
LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>> kEvents;

List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // kEvents is a linkedHashMap
    for (int i = 0; i < eventDoc.length; i++ ) {
      DateTime eventDate = eventDoc[i].eventDate;
      DateTime eventDateUTC = eventDate.toUtc();
      if (day.year == eventDate.year && day.day == eventDate.day && day.month == eventDate.month) {
        List<Event> eventList;
        eventList.addAll(eventDoc[i]);
        return kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList);
      }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

type 'Event' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

This is the Event class:

```
class Event {
  final String eventName;
  //final TimeOfDay eventStartTime;
  final DateTime eventStartTime;
  final String eventDuration;
  final DateTime eventDate;
  final String eventDescription;
  final String agentId;
  final String agencyId;


  Event(
      {this.eventName,
      this.eventStartTime,
      this.eventDuration,
      this.eventDate,
      this.eventDescription,
      this.agentId,
      this.agencyId});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'agentId': agentId,
      'agencyId': agencyId,
    };
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  Event.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        agentId = firestore['agentId'],
        agencyId = firestore['agencyId'];
}
```

This is a sample of the event record in Firestore:
[image]

Can someone please help me here with the .addAll method or show me a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

eventList.add(Event) and eventList.addAll(Iterable),
whereas eventDoc[i] is an Event not an Iterable.

Comment: Thank you @mario francios for you clarification. I changed the code to this: eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agencyId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agenctId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDate);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDescription);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDuration);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventName);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventStartTime);   but now I get this error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Event'. How do I add these data elements to the list?